# Binding to interface and displaying properties in base interface

Tags: c#, datagridview, interface, datasource

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539568/binding-ilistimyinterfacetype-doesnt-display-members-of-interfaces-that-imyint) (along with its answer) explains why you can't easily bind a DataGridView to an interface type and get columns for properties inherited from a base interface.

The suggested solution is to implement a custom TypeConverter. My attempt is below. However,  creating a DataSource and DataGridView bound to ICamel still only results in one column (Humps). I don't think that my converter is being used by .NET to decide which properties it can see for ICamel. What am I doing wrong?

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Legs { get; set; }
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public interface ICamel : IAnimal
{
    int Humps { get; set; }
}

public class MyConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        if(value is Type && (Type)value == typeof(ICamel))
        {
            List<PropertyDescriptor> propertyDescriptors = new List<PropertyDescriptor>();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(ICamel)))
            {
                propertyDescriptors.Add(pd);
            }
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(IAnimal)))
            {
                propertyDescriptors.Add(pd);
            }
            return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(propertyDescriptors.ToArray());
        }
        return base.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
    }

    public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Two other posts you might find interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/749542#750481 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882214#882246

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataGridView` does not use `TypeConverter`; **`PropertyGrid`** uses `TypeConverter`.

If it relates to list-controls like `DataGridView`, then the other answer is wrong.

To provide custom properties on a list, you need one of:

- `ITypedList` on the data-source
- `TypeDescriptionProvider` on the type

Both are non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you. It's not possible to apply `TypeDescriptionProvider` to an interface, but implementing `ITypedList` in my data source works perfectly at run-time. Seeing my custom properties at design-time would be nice, but I think I can find a workaround that will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

My Workaround happens in the binding of the dgv. 
I do need that the base interfaces and the inheriting interfaces remain in the same structure, just because i do other things width the final concerete class, not only show the data on a DataGridView. So, for example:

```
interface IGenericPerson
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}

interface IOperator : IGenericPerson
{
    bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

the concrete class:

```
class Operator : IOperator
{
    public Operator(){}

    public Operator(int id, string name, bool isAdmin)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        thsi.IsAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

and in a Gateway Class:

```
public IList<IOperator> GetOperators()
{
    IList<IOperator> list = new List<IOperator>();

    list.add(new Operator(112, "Mark Twain", false);
    list.add(new Operator(112, "Charles Manson", false);
    list.add(new Operator(112, "Richard Nixon", true);

    return list;
}
```

Now, if i try to bind a datagridView like this:

```
Gateway gt = new Gateway();
dgv.DataSource = gt.GetOperators();
```

I get a DataGridView with the only bool IsAdmin column from the IOperator Interface, not the ID, neither the Name propertys from its base interface.

but if I do this:

```
Gateway gt = new Gateway();

IList<IOperator> list = gt.GetOperators();

IList<Operator> ds = new List<Operator>();

foreach(IOperator op in list)
    ds.add((Operator)op);

dgv.DataSource = ds;
```

Everything works in the right way.

In this way i don't need to change the structure of the intarfaces chain, useful for other purposes, and only qhen displaying data i just insert the snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion would be to create a Interface that "reimplements" the propertys you want:

Let's say you have two interfaces:

```
public interface IHasName1
{
    String Name1 { get; set; }
}

public interface IHasName2 : IHasName1
{
    String Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

And a class that implements IHasName2:

```
public class HasTwoNames : IHasName2
{
    #region IHasName1 Member
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region IHasName2 Member
    public string Name2 {get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Now, thx for figuring that out btw., if you have a List with objects of concrete type HasTwoNames and you bind that list to a dgv, it only displays the member (Name2) of IHasName2.

A "workaround" is to create a new interface "IHasEverything" that inherits from IHasName2 and therefore from IHasName1 and reimplements the Propertys you need in your binding (you can do that with the new statement

```
public interface IHasEverything : IHasName2
{
    new String Name1 { get; set; }
    new String Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now your concrete class "HasTwoNames" needs to implement IHasEverything, too:

```
public class HasTwoNames : IHasName2, IHasEverything
{
    ...
}
```

You can bind this List to a datagridview:

```
    public List<IHasEverything> elements = new List<IHasEverything> {
        new HasTwoNames { Name1 = "Name1", Name2 = "Name2"},
        new HasTwoNames { Name1 = "Name3", Name2 = "Name4"},
    };
```

I know that this is just a workaround and only possible if you can modify the implementing class. But it works.
(If you remove a property from IHasName2, the code will still compile but you get a warning that IHasEverything does not need the new keyword.